# Being at a higher position than colleagues who have been with company longer than you

Tags: colleagues, conflict

I am soon going to be starting a job in where I will be significantly younger and less experienced than my colleages, who have been with the company for much longer, yet I will be in a higher position in terms of authority and pay.

How can I avoid conflicts with these colleagues? I would assume that there may be some jealousy of me born out of the matter that I am only just starting my career at this company and I am already being payed more than these colleagues, who have been at the company for significantly longer. Is there any way I can prevent this jealousy, and keep on positive terms with these colleagues?

Comment: duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/how-should-i-handle-my-new-job-as-manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption of jealousy may or may not be valid, actually, so it's worth going in with an open mind, and seeing the reaction you get.

If you do see people who are uncomfortable with your perceived youth and authority, your attitude is what will get you though it, specifically:

- Demonstrate why you're good at your job by doing it well - someone in
  authority who does their job well will usually make the work lives of
  people under them better, and this will raise your stock.
- Acknowledge that they have experience of the company that you don't, 
  by asking their opinions and advice in certain situations.
- Don't be arrogant - not that I think you will be, but sometimes people react to jealousy by bigging themselves up in justification, and this almost never works. Just do the job, as well as you can, and the rest will follow.

Good luck with the new role, enjoy it and you'll be fine.

Comment: Great answer, but if I may just add something : don't overdo the "not being arrogant" part. Of course you should ask for more experienced people's opinion, and respect it. But that doesn't mean you should let them make the calls. At the end of the day, you're in charge - act accordingly

Comment: I understand what you mean - there's a difference between "what's your opinion?" and "what should we do?" - essentially, if you're on the hook for the decision, you make the decision, but you need to be properly informed when making it.

Comment: Exactly my point :)

Comment: If you help them succeed by removing obstacles, giving clear direction and acting as a buffer between them and upper management then they likely won't care about your seniority!

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to @truedub's answer:

**Don't point out the differences**. You're obviously painfully aware that you might be earning more and have higher responsibility. That doesn't mean anyone else wants it pointed out to them.

(I'm not saying I think you necessarily would have done, by the way. I just didn't want to leave it unmentioned)

Comment: And they may not be aware of the difference in pay!